# Problem in installing CPLEX on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install CPLEX_12.63 on Ubuntu. My operations are:

```
chmod +x COSCE1263LIN64.bin
./COSCE1263LIN64.bin
```

Then the error shows up:

> bash: ./COSCE1263LIN64.bin: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I am using ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64

Comment: Where did you get the `.bin` file from?

Comment: I get the .bin file from IBM official web site "community version" [link](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/websphere/products/optimization/cplex-studio-community-edition/)

Answer (score -1):

I am using the same Ubuntu and CPLEX version and all runs fine. Probably your download was corrupted.